# is there any way to show the columns of a GridView in different rows?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, gridview

I have a ListView that is going to show some values of a Google calendar event, the application let you see what events do you have for one specific date, and you can add more, edit, or delete the events.

By the moment, i am showing all the events just for testing, and i am using a gridview for the properties to reorder and the headers, but the event have too much values and is too wide, what i want is split this columns in two rows

Column A, Column B, Column C
info      info      info

Column D, Column E...
info      info

for each element.

Instead of
Column A, B, C...
info info info info

in one row.

is there any way to do this with gridview? or i have to resign myself and do something similar with custom controls or Grids.

My listview

```
<ListView Background="Transparent" 
                  x:Name="DatosEvento"
                  Margin="5"
                  MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Calendar}"
                  Width="Auto"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Eventos}"
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Grid.Column="1">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Organizador" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Organizer.DisplayName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Correo Organizador">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Organizer.Email}" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Nombre Evento" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Summary}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Estado" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Status}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Fecha Fin" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=End.Date}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Actualizado el" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Updated.Date}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Enlace">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=HtmlLink}" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: This is not possible with the default `GridView`. The problem with this layout is that the user would have to scroll down to find the next columns. If your table has 1,000 rows the user would have to scroll over all this rows just to find the data of the next columns. This is far from intuitive and also has negative impact on the readability of the data set as related data i.e. rows would be separated. Instead of scrolling vertically to find columns, it is more convenient to scroll vertically. Vertical scroll bars will show automatically if columns are outside the viewport of the `GridView`.

Comment: Maybe the view or control you chose is the wrong choice. Maybe you should present your data differently. Maybe you should create an event item data class, which stores the event data of a single event. Then populate a `ListBox` with a collection of this event items, where `ListBox.ItemPanel` is set to use a `WrapPanel`. You can set the width of this panel to control the number of items before the wrapping occures.

Comment: Ok, i am doing a mix with gridview and stackpanels to do something similar, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i cant mark a comment as the solution, i have change the gridview for a mix of wrap and stackpanels, as @BionicCode suggested (he suggested the wrappanel i just added some stackpanels to do something similar to the gridview)